# How to get the number of pages in a view template?

Tags: theming, 8

I'm trying to get the number of total "pager" pages with a view by using the **views-mini-pager.html.twig**. Here is my code so far...

```
{% if items.previous or items.next %}
<nav class="pagination" role="navigation">
            {% if items.previous %}
                {% if items.current %}
                    {% trans %}
                    <span class="page-number">Page {{ items.current }}</span>
                    {% endtrans %}
                {% endif %}
                    <a class="newer-posts" href="{{ items.previous.href }}"><span aria-hidden="true">←</span>{{ items.previous.text|default('‹‹'|t) }}</a>
            {% endif %}
            {% if items.next %}
                {% if items.current %}
                    {% if items.previous %}
                    {% else %}
                        {% trans %}
                        <span class="page-number">Page {{ items.current }}</span>
                        {% endtrans %}
                    {% endif %}
                {% endif %}
                <a class="older-posts" href="{{ items.next.href }}">{{ items.next.text|default('››'|t) }}<span aria-hidden="true">→</span></a>
            {% endif %}
    </nav>
{% endif %}
```

I want to have something like this

[image]

And currently, I can only get the current number page which ends up like this ...

[image]

I have searched for the variables inside of **views-mini-pager.html.twig** and I have not found the number of pages.

My question is...

- How can I get the number of pages total? So I can display it at **views-mini-pager.html.twig**

  - For instance, if I view is divided into three pages I want to display "Page 1 of 3"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mini Pager doesn't give you that information. It's designed to not execute a count query. It just knows that there's at least one additional result (because it actually queries 21 if you show 21).

Comment: Just out curiosity, Do you know if there is another setting that provides this information ?

Comment: Not directly I fear. The normal Full pager works with that information, that's basically the page ID in the "Last" link. It doesn't seem to be available directly in the template. See template_preprocess_pager(), $pager_max is what you're looking for, mor or less. Which in turn is in the $pager_total global (yeah, there are still some of those left in dark corners of D8 and pager is a very dark corner). So, implement your own preprocess, and then put it in $variables so you can use it in your template.

Comment: I think in d9 has no more this global variable "$pager_total"

Answer (score 4):

This is also an option:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_HOOK().
 */
function MYTHEME_preprocess_pager(array &$vars) {
    $element = $vars['pager']['#element'];
    $pager_manager = \Drupal::service('pager.manager');
    $pager = $pager_manager->getPager($element);
    $vars['pager_max'] = $pager->getTotalPages();
}
```

Found this option here: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_pager/9.0.x

Answer (score 3):

Berdir is right: the full pager needs to be used. Three steps are involved to get the output you wanted:

1. Switch the Views pager type to the `full` pager
2. Implement a [`hook_preprocess_pager()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Render!theme.api.php/function/hook_preprocess_HOOK/8.2.x) function

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_HOOK().
 */
function MYTHEME_preprocess_pager(array &$variables) {
  // @see globals.api.php
  global $pager_total;
  $element = $variables['pager']['#element'];
  // Get the max page number for the current pager.
  $variables['pager_max'] = $pager_total[$element];
}
```

3. Override the default pager template

Put something like this in `pager.html.twig`:

```
{#
/**
 * @file
 * Theme override to display a pager.
 *
 * @see template_preprocess_pager()
 */
#}
{% if items %}
  <nav class="pager" role="navigation" aria-labelledby="pagination-heading">
    <h4 id="pagination-heading" class="visually-hidden">{{ 'Pagination'|t }}</h4>
    <ul class="pager__items js-pager__items">
      {# Print previous item if we are not on the first page. #}
      {% if items.previous %}
        <li class="pager__item pager__item--previous">
          <a href="{{ items.previous.href }}" title="{{ 'Go to previous page'|t }}" rel="prev"{{ items.previous.attributes|without('href', 'title', 'rel') }}>
            <span class="visually-hidden">{{ 'Previous page'|t }}</span>
            <span aria-hidden="true">{{ items.previous.text|default('‹ Previous'|t) }}</span>
          </a>
        </li>
      {% endif %}
      {# Now generate the actual pager piece. #}
      {% for key, item in items.pages %}
        {% if current == key %}
          <li class="pager__item is-active">
            {% trans %}
              Page {{ current }} of {{ pager_max }}
            {% endtrans %}
          </li>
        {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
      {# Print next item if we are not on the last page. #}
      {% if items.next %}
        <li class="pager__item pager__item--next">
          <a href="{{ items.next.href }}" title="{{ 'Go to next page'|t }}" rel="next"{{ items.next.attributes|without('href', 'title', 'rel') }}>
            <span class="visually-hidden">{{ 'Next page'|t }}</span>
            <span aria-hidden="true">{{ items.next.text|default('Next ›'|t) }}</span>
          </a>
        </li>
      {% endif %}
    </ul>
  </nav>
{% endif %}
```

The template is based on the template provided by Classy theme. It's inside the `{% trans %}` block where the magic happens.

Comment: i think in d9 has no more this global variable "$pager_total"

Answer (score 1):

Drupal 9 has a service that provides the pager data. Use the following in a preprocess to get the total number of pages:

```php
$total_pages = \Drupal::service('pager.manager')->getPager()->getTotalPages();
```

Answer (score -1):

In Drupal 9, you can put this line in pager.html.twig:

```
Page {{ current }} of {{ items.pages|length }}
```

Twig lets you output the length of the Twig array as a number of items in the array. This equals the total number of pages.

The `$pager_total` global variable mentioned earlier is no longer available in Drupal 9.

Make sure you  change your view settings to use a full pager. You can further modify pager.html.twig so that it looks like a mini pager by removing stuff you don't need.

No preprocess functions needed.

Comment: Drupal 9 has a service that provides the pager data. Use the following in a preprocess to get the total number of pages:  

``` lang-php
    $total_pages = \Drupal::service('pager.manager')->getPager()->getTotalPages();
```